# Highcharts Treemap with multiple series: getting them all to show in legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So I have 6 series I'm using in a single highcharts treemap chart where each series is it's own, smaller tree map. I can't get each of the names of the series to appear in the legend because the showInLegend property is a level above the data property.

I've tried two different configurations. First: series is set to my chartData variable, which looks like:
    [{
      name: key,
      stack: key,
      id: key,
      showInLegend: true,
      color: colors[key],
      data: sliced
    },
    {...}]
And so forth. This gives me a single treemap chart with each series underneath the previous, aka they are stacked on top of each other.

If I combine them all into a single data array, I can get the proper chart format I'm looking for, where each individual series is grouped by color/parent and so forth. This was done using data-less data points, like so:
{
   name,
   id,
   showInLegend,
   color
}

and each of the other points then would be:
   {
          name
          parent
          value
        }

This large data array is then given to a series array that looks like: 
[{
 type: 'treemap',
 layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
 data: dataArray from above,
}]

Again, I want the chart to be multiple tree maps, not one jammed on top of the other. But i also need the legend to show all of those series' names

Comment: I would throw a jfiddle up, but my series is some ~6k points

Comment: You need to create a minimal example. That could be done with less points.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unofficial `legendType: 'point'` property and remove unnecessary elements in `afterGetAllItems` legend event:

```
var H = Highcharts;

H.addEvent(H.Legend, 'afterGetAllItems', function(e) {
    e.allItems.splice(2, 6);
});

H.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        legendType: 'point',
        showInLegend: true,
        ...
    }]
});
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gp2qmvac/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.treemap.showInLegend

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts